# Rss feed not displaying as feed in browsers

Tags: php, xml, rss

```
<?php
  include 'classes/db.connect.php';
  if (isset($_GET['user'])) {
    if($blog->blog_check($_GET['user'])) {
      $username = strip_tags($_GET['user']);
    } else {
      http_response_code(404); include('html/blogs/404.html'); die;
    }
  } else {
    http_response_code(404); include('html/blogs/404.html'); die;
  }
  $current_page = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] !== 'off' ? 'https' : 'http') . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
  $url = $blog->get_blogger_branding($username, 'gravurl');
  $img = 'assets/blogs/images/'.$_GET['user'].'.png';
  file_put_contents($img, file_get_contents($url));
  $fbimg = 'https://afpayday.com/assets/blogs/images/'.$_GET['user'].'.png';

  header('Content-Type: application/rss+xml');
  echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <rss version="2.0" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
      <channel>
        <title>'.ucfirst($blog->get_blogger_branding($username, "fname")).'\'s Payday Blog</title>
        <description>Learn about affiliate marketing and affiliate product reviews.</description>
        <link>https://afpayday.com/'.$username.'</link>
        <copyright>Copyright 2020 Affiliate Payday</copyright>
        <language>en-us</language>
        <managingEditor>admin@afpayday.com (Bruce Bates)</managingEditor>
        <pubDate>Sun, 23 Feb 2020 09:50:44 -0700</pubDate>
        <webMaster>admin@afpayday.com (Bruce Bates)</webMaster>
        <atom:link href="https://afpayday.com/'.$username.'/rss/" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" />
        <image>
          <url>'.$fbimg.'</url>
          <title>'.ucfirst($blog->get_blogger_branding($username, "fname")).'\'s Payday Blog</title>
          <link>https://afpayday.com/'.$username.'</link>
          <description>'.ucfirst($blog->get_blogger_branding($username, "fname")).'\'s Photo</description>
          <width>144</width>
          <height>144</height>
        </image>
        <item>
          <title>Test</title>
          <guid>https://afpayday.com/'.$username.'</guid>
        </item>
      </channel>
    </rss>
  ';
?>
```

According to the w3 validator my feed is correctly coded. https://validator.w3.org/feed/check.cgi?url=https%3A%2F%2Fafpayday.com%2Fviraladmin%2Frss%2F

However browsers are not treating it as I would expect.

Firefox tries to download the feed as a file.

Chrome, Opera, and Edge show the feed as code instead of displaying it as a document tree which is what I normally see when viewing an RSS feed.

Only Internet Explorer seems to be handling it properly and showing the "would you like to subscribe to this feed" option.

The feed is here: https://afpayday.com/viraladmin/rss/

I would expect it to look more like https://www.feedforall.com/sample.xml in a browser

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: *Chrome, Opera, and Edge show the feed as code instead of displaying it as a document tree*, Are you Sure you have php tags opened and closed correctly ? See this tutorial https://www.webslesson.info/2019/03/creating-valid-rss-feed-in-php.html?m=1

Comment: I updated the code to display the entire codeset including the php. I generally don't close php tags as its not required https://www.php.net/basic-syntax.instruction-separation but to rule that problem out I did add it and test to be sure - same result.

Comment: You helped me sort the issue. Seems that I had to use `header('Content-Type: text/xml');` not ` header('Content-Type: application/rss+xml');`. Is weird as every tutorial I have found until now says to use application/rss+xm not text/xml.

Comment: Glad you solved.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is just the way the world works - `application/rss+xml` is the "correct" mime type, but browsers do not always follow "correct" (instead they go for "common" - which can end up self-fulfilling, since the common thing is to do whatever most browsers support)